What empirical evidence is there that the separation between analysis and design leads to better results than mixing them?
What scientific/empirical evidence is there that the mental separation between (business) analysis and (technical) design in software development leads to better results than considering both together?
Background: I'm talking about separation on a small scale here, i.e., for a single user story, separate between "acceptance criteria" that document what shall be done from a requirements-centric, non-technical point of view and "design+implementation" that determines how the acceptance criteria are implemented in a specific solution.
I'm NOT talking about "first do all the analysis, then do all the design" (big design up front); which is assumed to be bad.
I'm also NOT talking about "don't change the analysis once you have started design" (pure waterfall); which is assumed to be bad, too.
I always considered it rather obvious that such a separation between analysis and design is beneficial. And there is lots of advice that says this is a good thing, sometimes using different words like "requirements", "opportunity space vs solution space", "domain-driven design", ... but essentially meaning the same idea: Don't mix up problem and solution, but have a clear mental separation of them.
But recently a co-worker challenged why we should do so. And I realized that apart from "common sense" and logically deductive arguments, I don't know of real empirical evidence that shows that such a separation is good. In which "good" could be anything from "less effort" over "better solutions" to "more maintainable software".
Do you know any empirical studies?

I'm afraid asking for resources is off-topic for this community. This is an interesting question, though. I'm not sure how you can [edit] your question to eliminate the request for resources, which asking for links or references to studies would fall into that category.

"What scientific/empirical evidence is there that the mental separation between (business) analysis and (technical) design in software development leads to better results than considering both together?" - none, because the statement is wrong, at least in this generality.

... of course, separating analysis from design, and not mixing up problem and solution is often a good idea (but not always).

Agree with Doc, don't half solve something as part of problem statement and then take that as solution starting point, because solving the original problem may be easier than solving the half-baked one.

"What empirical evidence is there" is a subtly loaded question about the allegedly inherent existence of such information. First and foremost, does your claim even hold water? Your question spends no effort justifying it (other than you stating you find it obvious), and it is not an evident truth. Your summation of "Don't mix up problem and solution" is a wild claim with no real roots. You seem to assert that separation is the mutual complement of mixing; but you are effectively shutting out the most realistic scenario of considering both at the same time without conflating them.

The point I'm getting at here is that you're trying to formulate a question without really bothering to anchor it to verifiable claims, commonly understood truths, or unambiguous phrasings; which turns this more into a "vet my claims for me" request rather than a genuine request for information. Additionally, your goal here seems to succumb to a variation of the XY problem as requiring empirical evidence is not really a reasonable standard to uphold in the pursuit of the conversation that sparked this.

Depending on what you mean by this, this may not be a very controversial claim. E.g. this could just mean that, while technical details are important, what's more important is to nail down exactly what is it that the business actually needs, so that you don't build the wrong thing; decide on the technical details in the service of that. Often, instead of stating what the core problem is, clients will come asking for what they perceive to be a technical solution ("Rewrite in a fancy framework following all the best practices!"), and you need to look past that and dig deeper ("Ok, but why?").

@DocBrown You're right, the phrasing is a bit too general. If there is evidence for a specific sub-case, I'm interested in it, too.

@Flater If there is evidence to the contrary, I'm interested in it, too! And "considering both at the same time without conflating them" is, to me, a special case of "separation". Perhaps this is a language issue, but I consider "mental separation" as synonymous to "no conflating".

@T.Baum: you are asking for empirical evidence in form of some scientific paper, that's a 3rd party resource request, hence off-topic in this site (and I have no idea of such a thing exists, that's probably in the domain of neuro scientists, not software engineers).  Moreover, I think your question is vague, since the terms "analysis" and "design" (and their "mental separation") leaves a lot room for interpretation - and what counts as a "better" result. is quite debatable.

... if you, however, accept anecedotal evidence: there is a reason why the term XY problem became popular - asking about an attempted solution Y instead of the problem X is a form of jumping "too early" into the "design" instead of staying open for a thorough analysis, and it seems to hapen so often that people invented a term for it.

Thanks for the reply and the anecdotal evidence. Regarding 3rd party resource requests: After posting my question, I read the corresponding meta article. I agree that an empirical scientific study is an external resource, but I disagree that asking for one bears the problems listed in the meta article: It does not give rise to opinions as answers, and the answers will not be outdated shortly. You could count it as lazyness, asking on SE instead of searching the web and thinking for myself (which I did to some degree). But this is true for a lot of questions on SE.

@T.Baum: our community simply does not accept question which are primarily 3rd party resource requests, regardless what reasons the meta article lists. We like to share our experts knowledge, and this will include common sense and "logically deductive arguments" - both are things which you categorically ruled out. In sense, this question looks like an XY problem - you asked for an approach to argue with your colleague, and already mixed it up with the "design" = "type of solution must be an empirical study".

@T.Baum: The reasons listed in the meta article are examples for context. They are not a complete list of every conceivable underlying reason for the rule with an implicit allowance that everything not on the list gets a free pass.

maybe : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251890293_The_basis_for_building_a_business_case_in_software_development_a_case_study ? I think the problem is you are using terms quite loosely. who exactly is suggesting that BAs should write software? what name do they give this idea?

If you rule out stereotypical waterfall-style constraints (all the analysis precedes all the design, with no revisits), but instead consider the ideal to be an oscillation back and forth within a small-grained scope, then in what sense are they separate even in your own idea?
"Analysis" tends to emphasise the investigation of the problem, whereas "design" tends to emphasise finding solutions to known problems, but I would say the distinctions in these two activities are vague rather than strict. And it's not uncommon that design throws previously unperceived problems into relief.
When conceived as a separate activity, the analysis stage tends to be about articulating the problem in writing, and is done best by people also broadly experienced in design, since this increases their ability to perceive problems.
The purpose of this activity is not to isolate analysis from design, but to produce an intermediary artefact - a written, and therefore communicable, description of the existing situation, prior to any proposed changes.
The fact that analysis and design are talked about separately doesn't mean they are done separately, any more so than talking of the left leg and the right leg separately, means each leg walks separately. The walking of the two legs, and which foot you start or finish on, or where your weight is borne at any one time, are usually relatively unimportant to the outcome of walking a distance.
When a development project requires more than one person due to its scale, that's when it becomes necessary for things to be communicable.
When something is small enough not to need communicable analysis, then a single person is likely to do analysis and design themselves like walking.

To stay in your "legs" analogy: What I'm interested in is whether it is better to have two legs as distinguishable entities (at least in the mind of the person doing the analysis, and if there are several people involved also in the communication) or to have both legs tied together. In its core, this is a distinction in the mind of the people involved, not necessarily a distinction in time, roles, ...

@T.Baum, once you're down to what one person is doing purely inside their own head (as opposed to what's happening with a division of labour in a team), I think the distinction between analysis and design melts away. There's no reason to think that purely internal episodes of cognition proceed in the same way or under the same constraints as episodes of teamwork do.

@T.Baum, (just thinking more about this...) the key point with "analysis" when done as a division of labour, is that the divisions of labour are drawn according to what is suitable for one person to get on with independently, without excessive waiting on others or chatter between people (in the sense in which these things are considered inefficiencies). When you're inside your own mind, it's less clear that there are different parts of your own cognition that are delayed in waiting, or which involve overhead of communication. (1/2)

Therefore, it's possible for your mind to behave in ways that are optimal for the task (such as bouncing back and forth with attention), but would be wildly inefficient behaviours when involving two people performing divided roles. Therefore, even if the mind does have a perceivable division of labour on a task, it doesn't necessarily follow the contours of multi-person divisions of labour, because the divisions in each context are chosen to avoid different kinds of inefficiencies. (2/2)

I will focus on the acceptance criteria that you seem to categorize in the analysis:

for a single user story, separate between "acceptance criteria" that document what shall be done from a requirements-centric, non-technical point of view and "design+implementation" that determines how the acceptance criteria are implemented in a specific solution

Considering that a user story is the placeholder for a conversation, the reason is that the acceptance criteria should be agreed with the user, and the user understand best the problem space.
Moreover, the acceptance criteria
should be aligned with the user's goals. Having it bound with the designed solution would close the door to creative alternatives that might emerge to be "better" (whatever this should mean) than the first design. In other words, having acceptance criteria in the problem space is more open to change within a sprint.
Last but not least, acceptance criteria elaborated with the user in the problem space also allows to better understand what the user is really looking for.
Now is there a study that documents this? Maybe, but such a study would only make sense if we could isolate the impact of the acceptance criteria from the impact of the user story itself, and this on a representative number of projects, whereas in reality the personal abilities and expertise of team members is what will have the most impact on the results.

I agree with your arguments for keeping acceptance criteria in problem space. And I totally agree that it is hard to do such a study and to keep confounding factors under control. Still, I think it would be possible to do a study at least for sub-hypotheses of the general hypothesis in the question. And given that the stated assumption is a foundation of most development processes currently around, I hoped that perhaps someone had tested it.

Thank you for the feedback. I have looked on dl.acm.org and stumbled accross some studies that suggest that my negative arguments are even worse since some studies look even at the impact of the form of acceptance criteria (formal languagage vs natural language) but none seem have measured efficiency but most rely on feedback of developers about the use of one or the other technique. Which confirms my blunt statement about the difficulty to isolate the impacts.
